# Why is 1e-12 + 1 = 1 in C++, but not in C?

Tags: c++

In C I put in a big number, like 1e-12, in float data and add 1. It's gave me a correct answer.

In C++ I made the same, but when I add 1 to 1e-12, it returns me 1.

```
float a = 1e-12;
std::cout << "The number is : " << a + 1 << std::endl;
```

Output:

The number is: 1

I don't have any error messages. The program just returns the wrong result.

(!! 1e-12 + 1 is not equal to 1!!)

Comment: `1e12` is not the same thing as `1e-12`.

Comment: because 1e12 != 1e-12. one is too big, another is too small (closer to 0)

Comment: `1e-12` is not a big number but a small number. It is `0.000000000001`. The result of `1e-12+1` is the same in both C and C++ (or any other language). What differs is the (default) precision you use to print the result in each language.

Comment: you can't compare two float numbers, also 1e-12 is very small compared to 1
comparing two float number is like  if(a - b < very_small_number) {do_somthing();}

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) is still relevant 3 decades later.

Comment: This may help: http://ideone.com/hYli0Z

Comment: My error I mean 1e-12 not 1e12 (you can see it in the code). And I modify the code.

Comment: @phoenixstudio -- you **absolutely can** compare floating-point values. Whether the results are meaningful depends on where those values came from. And "nearly equals" (i.e. a-b<very_small_number) has its own set of quirks and is not a universal replacement for equality tests. In particular, a "nearly equals" b and b "nearly equals" c does not imply that a "nearly equals" c.

Comment: Pete Becker equality between float depend on the domain, for example sqrt(10)*sqrt(10)!=10, even though we know it does technically, for that reason ppl tend to not compare floating point variable directly because it is a source of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers by default take some short-cuts when doing floating-point math. (They typically have a command-line switch to enforce the rules)

In this case, the rule is that the compiler should store the **double** value `1e-12` as a **float** in `a`, and then, in the output statement, add 1 to the stored value.

The optimization is probably that one of the compilers never stored the value; instead, it added 1 to the **double** value `1e-12`. With the higher precision initial value there are more low bits in the fraction part, and that will affect the result of adding 1.

So the results can be different, depending on how the compiler treats those values.

That's just handwaving, though; if this is really important to you, look at the machine code that the compiler generates in both cases to see what's being done differently.